# Nuget restore not working for Xamarin form on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, xamarin.forms, msbuild, jenkins-plugins

I am trying for CI: integrating xamarinform with jenkins.

Having installed visual studio for Mac

Using following command for nuget restore
                                            :
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono --
    runtime=v4.0

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/nuget/nuget.exe restore XamarinSampleCI.sln

But getting following error:

```
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.0' from   '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.16.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin'.
MsBuild.exe does not exist at '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.16.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin'.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Duplicate issue here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17705/command-line-build-and-nuget-packages

Comment: I have updated question as per duplicate issue link but still getting error with different logs. please check above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jenkin, we need to install plugin Environment Injector Plugin, and set environment variable as PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:$PATH

Got help from this link:
https://www.junian.net/xamarin-jenkins-hockeyapp/